# Is it possible to get complete results by Facebook FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I tried some FQL queries by using Facebook Graph API Explorer. 
But I found I couldn't get complete results, it missed many records. 
ex:
Select uid, message, place_id, time  from status  where uid= me()  order by time desc.

I think I get less than 10% of the real result.

Is there any tip that I can get complete data by FQL?

Thanks,
Leon

Answer (score 0):

You have to impose a constraint at the end of the query, for example "LIMIT 1000" or specify a created_time, otherwise the results will be incomplete.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried to add time constraint, ex:
Select uid, message, place_id, time  from status  where uid= me()  and time  > 1385856000 order by time desc limit 10

But still can't get complete data, for the time, I have tried 12/15, 12/14 and 12/1...

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Maybe this is the reason: "The status table is limited to the last 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater" 
source: http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FQL:status